# How to grant privileges to mysql user? CentOS 6 and ZPAnel

Tags: centos6

Installed ZPanel on CentOS 6. Created user, added database. But user has no privileges.

Tried to create in SQL shell with

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* To 'name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxxx';
```

get `#1044 - Access denied for user 'name'@'%' to database 'db_name'`

What need to do to grant privileges?

Comment: Have you done `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to login with the root account to do this.  If you created a user call it jsmith and are trying to create another user account jdoe, you must first login with root to give jsmith grant rights.  The question is who are you logged in as right now running this command?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Logged in as root user and can change privileges etc. I was logged in as another user, created at ZPanel